# Batch file FOR loop to copy folders only if they exist in another folder

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm trying to write a batch file that copies folders from one folder location to another, but only if they exist in a third folder.

That sounds confusing, I'll try again.

I have the following 3 folders:

- Updates
- Applications
- Previous Versions

Before updating the `\Applications` subfolder structure with the [new version] `\Updates` subfolder structure, I need to copy the `\Applications` subfolder structure to the `\Previous Versions` folder. Once that is complete then it needs to copy the `Updates` subfolder structure to the `/Applications` folder.

I got as far as the following:

```
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

Set UpdtRoot=C:\Test\Updates
Set AppsRoot=C:\Test\Apps
Set PVerRoot=C:\Test\Previous Versions

FOR /d %%i IN ("!UpdtRoot!\*.*") DO xcopy "!AppsRoot!\%%~nxi" "!PVerRoot!\%%~nxi\" /e
```

This doesn't work though, it copies all the folders from AppsRoot into PVerRoot.

I need it to copy subfolders from `AppsRoot` to `PVerRoot`, but only if they exist in `UpdtRoot`. I only need it to copy the folders and subfolders ONLY so no files at all.

Comment: Forgot to say, it's only folders that I need to copy.

Comment: There's no need to keep the whole pre-updated version. I'd just like to be able copy only those folders that are going to be updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've included a batch script that should complete what you explain to copy all subfolders recursively from the `/Applications` directory to the `/Previous Versions` directory, but ONLY if those same directories 'to copy' exist in the `/Updates` directory.

#### Notable Items

- Ensure the `SET NewCopyDir=%CopyDir:C:\Test\Apps\=%` has the `C:\Test\Apps\` characters in it to match the `Applications` directory full path including the ending backslash. This is the logic that parses that out to append to the end of the `/Updates` and `/Previous Versions` directories so the `XCOPY` commands will copy those directories over accordingly.
- The `Root` part off the names were taken off of the `SET` variables for the directories but that doesn't really matter, but I shorted them up to have it look a little cleaner in the script logic.

### Batch Script

```
@ECHO ON

SET "Updt=C:\Test\Updates"
SET "Apps=C:\Test\Apps"
SET "PVer=C:\Test\previous Versions"
IF NOT EXIST "%Updt%" MD "%Updt%"
IF NOT EXIST "%Apps%" MD "%Apps%"
IF NOT EXIST "%PVer%" MD "%PVer%"

FOR /D %%S IN ("%Apps%\*") DO (
    CALL :Routine "%%~S"
)
GOTO :EOF

:Routine
SET CopyDir=%~1
SET NewCopyDir=%CopyDir:C:\Test\Apps\=%
IF EXIST "%Updt%\%NewCopyDir%" XCOPY /E /T "%Apps%\%NewCopyDir%" "%PVer%\%NewCopyDir%\"
GOTO :EOF
```

---

### Supporting Resources

- [CALL](http://ss64.com/nt/call.html)
- [XCOPY](http://ss64.com/nt/xcopy.html)

  > ```
  >   /E           Copies directories and subdirectories, including empty ones.
  >                Same as /S /E. May be used to modify /T.
  >
  >   /T           Creates directory structure, but does not copy files. Does not
  >                include empty directories or subdirectories. /T /E includes
  >                empty directories and subdirectories.
  > ```